# $\mathbb RP^2$ covered by open sets $U_1, \dots, U_n$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\mathbb RP^2$ be covered by open sets $U_1, \dots, U_n$ such that every $U_i$ is homeomorphic to the plane $\mathbb R^2$. Set $V_i = U_1 \cup \dots \cup U_i$ for $1 \leq i < n.$
Show that there exists an $i \leq n$ such that $U_i \cap V_{i-1}$ is empty or not connected.

I'm doing this exercise as part of my Algebraic Topology lecture. We are currently discussing the Seifert-Van Kampen theorem, so I thought I should try to solve it in this manner. But I haven't had luck so far, so I'm just asking if this approach should work or if there's a better way to solve it.

Comment: You can try inductively calculating $\pi_1(V_i)$ by using the Seifert-van Kampen theorem. Then compare the result with what you hopefully already know about $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^2)$.

Comment: What went wrong with your SVK attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us condider more generally open simply connected $U_i$ covering $\mathbb RP^2$. In your question we have $U_i \approx \mathbb R^2$.

Define $V_i = U_1 \cup \ldots \cup U_i$ for $i =1, \ldots, n$.

Assume that all $D_i = U_{i+1} \cap V_i$ are non-empty and connected, $i = 1,\ldots,n-1$. Since $\mathbb RP^2$ is locally path connected, connectedness and pathwise connectedness agree for open subsets. Thus all $D_i$ are pathwise connected. This also implies that all $V_i$ are pathwise connected.

Now we can inductively show that all $\pi_1(V_i) = 0$. Since the $V_i$ are pathwise connected, the choice of a basepoint is irrelevant to compute $\pi_1(V_i)$.

The base case $i = 1$ is trivial because $V_1 = U_1$.

$i \mapsto i+1$:

The Seifert - van Kampen theorem exhibits $\pi_1(V_{i+1})$ as a quotient group of $\pi_1(U_{i+1}) * \pi_1(V_i)$, where we take a basepoint in $D_i$. But $\pi_1(U_{i+1}) * \pi_1(V_i) = 0$, thus $\pi_1(V_{i+1}) = 0$.

We conclude that $\mathbb RP^2 = V_n$ is simply connected, a contradiction.